# Extract the 2048 vector of a fine-tuned Inception V3 on my own dataset on test set

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I have already finetuned an Inception V3 model on my dataset which was already pretrained on ImageNet.

Now, I need to load the save pt model and run it on test patches and extract the 2048 feature vector from Inception V3.

I am not sure what code snippet I should use for extracting feature vectors of size 2048 on an inception v3 model that is already finetuned on my own data (train data) on the test set.

```
import torch
model = torch.load('pt/model_ft_100e_best_acc.pt')
feature_extractor = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model.modules())[:-2]))
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

batch_size = 1

input_size = 299 # for Inception V3

data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_size, input_size)),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.6964, 0.4764, 0.6246], [0.1896, 0.2210, 0.1864]) 

    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_size, input_size)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.6964, 0.4764, 0.6246], [0.1896, 0.2210, 0.1864]) 
    ]),

    'test': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((input_size, input_size)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.6964, 0.4764, 0.6246], [0.1896, 0.2210, 0.1864]) 
    ])
}


data_dir = "/projectnb/ivcgroup/jalal/data/fold1/" # for running on SCC
# Create training and validation datasets
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x), data_transforms[x]) for x in ['test']}
# Create training and validation dataloaders

dataloaders_dict = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4) for x in ['test']}


sample_fnames_labels = dataloaders_dict['test'].dataset.samples
sample_large_images = {}


test_large_images = {}
test_loss = 0.0
test_acc = 0


with torch.no_grad():
    test_running_loss = 0.0
    test_running_corrects = 0
    print(len(dataloaders_dict['test']))
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders_dict['test']):
        print(i)
        test_input = inputs.to(device)
        test_label = labels.to(device)
        test_output = feature_extractor(test_input) # here I need to get feature vectors of size 2048
        print("test feature size is: ", test_output.shape)
```

In my model, I do see that avgpool layer shows 2048. However, when I try this solution from @ptrblck  it doesn't recognize the syntax.

```
      (branch3x3dbl_3b): BasicConv2d(
        (conv): Conv2d(384, 384, kernel_size=(3, 1), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 0), bias=False)
        (bn): BatchNorm2d(384, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
      (branch_pool): BasicConv2d(
        (conv): Conv2d(2048, 192, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
        (bn): BatchNorm2d(192, eps=0.001, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      )
    )
    (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1, 1))
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
    (fc): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=2, bias=True)
  )
)>
```

I tried:
`model.avgpool.register_forward_hook(get_activation('avgpool'))`

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-can-l-load-my-best-model-as-a-feature-extractor-evaluator/17254/6?u=mona_jalal

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you saved the model right? and not only the state_dict?

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure about the way you loaded your model
refer [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) where they show correct way of loading and saving model .

Since you have used some pretrained model check the `dict` `keys` using

```
my_best_model = torch.load('model_best.pth.tar')
my_best_model.keys()
>>dict_keys(['epoch', 'state_dict', 'best_prec1', 'optimizer'])
```

where

```
my_model = net.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_best.pth.tar'))
my_best_model=my_model['state_dict']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
activation = {}
def get_activation(name):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        activation[name] = output.detach()
    return hook

# if trained with data parallel
model.module.avgpool.register_forward_hook(get_activation("avgpool"))

# if not trained with data parallel
model.avgpool.register_forward_hook(get_activation("avgpool"))
```

Credits to ptrblck in PyTorch forum.